# Storing items as cookies, works perfectly fine on a normal browser, but on a native device browser there are implications

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, mobile

I am creating a website for a client at the moment, we decided an easy way to store "items" which will be passed down to a subdomain from the root would be to store them as cookies. This works perfectly fine in a normal browser, yet when I tested it on a native device browser it didn't work as smoothly. I am wondering where some of these problems may have been coming from and hoping you wonderful developers can lend a man a hand.
The idea is that on the frontend when a "Your Order" side drawer is pressed, a function runs grabbing the cookies and then sorts them into their specified content area's -> Downloadable Content, Requested Material and Bespoke Content. I have created two separate functions for this, one that was the original working piece and another more tailored and "good practice".

Tried having the "Value" of the cookie containing the values that need to be stored such as, [itemname],[itemlocation], [itemdescription], [itemtype].
The second function stores the item data in an object, the object is then JSON.stringified and iterated over in a for loop. This is then taken out of a string with JSON.parse() and further iterated over in an .each() iterating over the index(key) and val(value).

FIRST FUNCTION:

```
$('section#review-downloads a.toggle-btn').bind('click tap', function() {
        let cookies;
        let itemSplit;
        var section = $('section#review-downloads');
        if(section.hasClass('active')) {
            section.removeClass('active');
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('section#review-downloads .selected-items div').find('p').remove();
            }, 900);
        } else {
            section.addClass('active');
            $.each(document.cookie.split(';'), function() {
                cookies = this.split('=');
                let trimId = cookies[0].trim();
                vals = cookies[1].replace(/[\])}[{(]/g, '');
                if(!(cookies[0] === "envFilter")) {
                    $.each(vals.split('[ ]'),function() {
                        itemSplit = this.split(',');
                        let itemId = trimId;
                        let itemName = itemSplit[0];
                        let itemUrl = itemSplit[1];
                        let itemType = itemSplit[2];
                        let itemDesc = itemSplit[3];
                        if(itemType === ' Downloadable Content ') {
                            $('<p id="selected-item-'+itemId+'"><strong>'+itemName+'</strong>'+itemDesc+'</p>').appendTo('section#review-downloads .review-container .selected-items .downloadable-content');
                        } else if (itemType === ' Requested Materials ') {
                            $('<p id="selected-item"><strong>'+itemName+'</strong>'+itemDesc+'</p>').appendTo('section#review-downloads .review-container .selected-items .requested-material');
                        } else if (itemType === ' Bespoke Content ') {
                            $('<p id="selected-item"><strong>'+itemName+'</strong>'+itemDesc+'</p>').appendTo('section#review-downloads .review-container .selected-items .bespoke-content');
                        }
                    });
                };
            });
        } 
        return false;
    });
```

THE SECOND FUNCTION (best practice)

```
$('div.support-item-wrapper div.order-add').bind('click tap', function() {
        let id = $(this).data('id');
        let name = $(this).data('title');
        let file = $(this).data('file');
        let type = $(this).data('type');
        let desc = $(this).data('description').replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");
        let url = $(this).data('url');

        let cookieVal = {
            name: name,
            file: file,
            type: type,
            desc: desc,
            url: url
        };
        let string = JSON.stringify(cookieVal);
        setCookie('product-'+id, string, 1);
    });

    $('section#review-downloads a.toggle-btn').bind('click tap', function() {
        var section = $('section#review-downloads');
        if(section.hasClass('active')) {
            section.removeClass('active');
        } else {
            section.addClass('active');
            let decoded_user_product;
            cookie_values = document.cookie.split(';');
            for(i = 0; i < cookie_values.length; i++) {
                cookie_split = cookie_values[i].split("=");
                cookie_key = cookie_split[0].trim();
                cookie_value = cookie_split[1].trim();
                // console.log(cookie_value);
                if(cookie_key != "envFilter") {
                    decoded_user_product = JSON.parse(cookie_value);
                }
                $.each(decoded_user_product, function(index, val) {
                    // console.log("index:" + index + "& val:" + val);
                    if(index === "name") {
                        console.log(val);
                    } else if (index === "type") {
                        console.log(val);
                    } else if (index === "desc") {
                        console.log(val);
                    }
                });
            }
            // console.log(decoded_user_product);
        };
    });
```

On Desktop, the results are perfectly fine. Each item is easily console.log()'able and has been easily sorted in the FIRST FUNCTION.
On Mobile, the same results were as to be expected. But after realising it hadn't worked I used chrome://inspect along with a lot of console.logs to come to the conclusion that I may be too inexperienced to understand what parts of my code are unable to run on a native browser.

Comment: Native implementations typically use local storage instead of cookies.

Comment: This is something I will definitely look into as its quite an easy switch to make in the functions I already have created. I am using just a basic setCookie() function that takes in a name, value and time but have used localStorage with React. You may have answered my prayers :)